# Lollipop update on MotoG causing no service for sim card

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, mobile-network, dual-sim

I was using Moto G(1st gen) phone for the past 1 year. I was using 2 sims and I didnt face any problem for 1 year. After getting lollipop update, I frequently get 'no service' for one of my sim. Initially I used to reboot the phone and it used to work. But nowadays, the issue is coming up frequently and doesnt always work with rebooting.
Any fixes, suggestions?

Comment: I Suggest you to make use of XDADevelopers forum regarding these kinds of handset issues ... You may Visit [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g "XDA Developers") !

Comment: Intermittent problems are typically an issue with hardware more than software in situations like this... I would suggest removing both SIMs, factory reset (wipe all data) and bring the phone up and set it up, then insert one SIM at a time and power cycle in between. If the problem recurs, try to get the troublesome SIM replaced, if it still continues it sounds like your device is in need or repair/replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I have a phone with the same symptoms, this worked for me, but the problem still reoccurs so I'm trying to find a better answer.

http://www.thecellguide.com/moto-g-noservice.php

In brief:

- Go into Settings -> Storage; tap Cached Data and select Ok to clear data
- Go into Settings -> More -> Cellular Networks -> Preferred network type

  - Select "2G"
- Turn the phone off, wait 10 seconds and then turn it back on.
- Go into Settings -> More -> Cellular Networks -> Preferred network type

  - Select "3G"
- Select Network Operators -> Search Networks
- Select the correct carrier and you should be all set.

I'm not sure if that article was written with the LTE version in mind, so I follow the instructions and then switch the preferred network type to LTE.